# Logstash Grok Compute match values

Tags: ruby, addition, logstash-grok

I'm trying to compute values from grok patterns. My data is sending from filebeat to logstash.

My simple grok pattern dor testing :

```
match => ["message", "^%{INT:nb1} \| %{INT:nb2}$"]
```

I want to add this 2 values (nb1 & nb2).

I tried this 2 possibilities :

```
mutate { add_field => { "test_Duration" => "%{nb1}+%{nb2}" } }
```

In result I had a string.

```
ruby {
            code => "
             res = event['nb1'].to_i + event['nb2'].to_i;
            event.set('test', res);  "
          }
```

In ruby code I can't get nb1 & nb2 values..

I don't know how to do this..

**============================
SOLUTION ============================**

Use ruby code with `event.get('var').to_i`

```
res =  event.get('nb1').to_i + event.get('nb2').to_i;
event.set('test', res);
```

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or similar phrases to your question when you've solved the problem. If someone gave you an answer, [accept it](/help/someone-answers). If you found a solution on your own, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) (you can also accept your own answer after two days). Accepting answers is also the way to show a question has been solved - editing "solved" into the question is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ruby code with `event.get('var').to_i`

```
res =  event.get('nb1').to_i + event.get('nb2').to_i;
event.set('test', res);
```